# Localizing validation (error) messages in Grails

Tags: grails, localization, internationalization

I try to localize error messages from the Domain classes. This is possible with the default error messages, e.g.:

> default.blank.message=Property [{0}] cannot be blank

and localized attribute names, e.g.:

> customer.address.label=Customer address

Where "Customer" is my domain class and address is its attribute.

My problem is that I can't localize some attributes because I need specific error messages.
E.g:

> has.to.be.a.number=Property [{0}] has to be a number
>
> contingent.size.label=Contingent size.

But the message I get is "Property [size] has to be a number" instead of "Property [Contingent size] has to be a number".

The messages I cant localize are following:

- Property [{0}] has to be a number
- Property [{0}] has to be a valid date  // I can't use g:datePicker in this context

---

I add some other example with some other domain class which also doesn't work

```
package cz.quanti.spaportal.touristOffice

import ...

class TouristOffice {  
    String customerNumber  
    int minimalContingent  
    Address address  
    User user  
    ContactPerson contactPerson  

    static hasMany = [contingents: Contingent]

    static constraints = {  
        customerNumber(unique:true, nullable: true, blank: true)  
        user(nullable: true, blank: true)  
        contactPerson(nullable: false)  
        minimalContingent(min: 0)  
        address(nullable: false)  
    }
```

Only the "minimalContingent" is not localized:  (the message is localized and the minimal attribute is not)
Property [minimalContingent] has to be a number.

Comment: What validators are you using? Please add your domain class code with constraints.

Comment: Are your domain classes in a package, or are they using the default package?

Comment: Additionally, are you having a problem specifically with getting labels to work, or with getting custom validation messages to work? I've assumed the former, but after re-reading your question am now a bit more fuzzy about which problem you're having.

Comment: @mflorian - I am using the standard grails validation, using constraints defined in the domain class.

Comment: @Rob Hruska - Well I would like to get the labels localized, because the messages work. But if there is no other possibility to do so I would like to do custom validation messages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that the whole path to the attribute (without "label" in the end) should work for you. Looks like this:

```
com.example.Customer.homeAddress=Customer address
```

remember to use lowercase and uppercase where they are needed!

Answer (score 4):

If you are having problem with validation messages you can always check the codes for the validation errors using the `errors` collection on an instance.

```
Customer c = ...

c.validate()

c.errors.each { println it }
c.errors.getFieldError("address").codes.each { println it }
c.errors.getFieldError("address").defaultMessage
```

Write a unit test to check the codes to localise the messages.

Comment: Well this seems to be a good idea. However, this prints only some of all errors (and the related codes) (with some I mean for instance 2(in Unit test) of 5(in gsp)). These errors I get are localized and work well (but some other errors which are not printed out are also working fine and some not).

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you're using the domain class package in your definitions. Also check your capitalization; I'm not sure if it makes a difference, but my successful `messages.properties` using labels have looked akin to the following:

```
// messages.properties
com.example.Customer.address.label=Customer address
com.example.Contingent.size.label=Contingent size

// or if you're using the default package
Customer.address.label=Customer address
...
```

---

After your update, can you clarify something? Do you have the following in your `messages.properties`:

```
cz.quanti.spaportal.touristOffice.TouristOffice.minimalContingent.label=...
```

If not, does it work if you add it?

Comment: I am NOT using the default package. However most of the default messages work in both cases: com.example.Customer.name.label=Name and customer.name.label=Name